# [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, file-upload

my code works fine in WAMP server without any warning. But when I upload same code on my server it shows me these arror.

> [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

my php file contain following line. $ran is random name generated by system. I want file name hidden, so I kept random function for that.

> move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "users/jagdish/".$ran);

I also tried full path "/home/user/public_html/" instead of giving only "users/".

There are two errors. My upload.php is located at /public_html/jagdish/upload/upload.php

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(/home/noyosdzy/public_html/jagdish/upload/users/jagdish/d406235ed72be6c41dbe2c00798a6e86fc28510f1359788762)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/noyosdzy/public_html/jagdish/upload/upload.php on
>   line 118
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move '/tmp/php3ww2M8' to
>   '/home/noyosdzy/public_html/jagdish/upload/users/jagdish/d406235ed72be6c41dbe2c00798a6e86fc28510f1359788762'
>   in /home/noyosdzy/public_html/jagdish/upload/upload.php on line 118

I tried different combinations also. But doesn't work. It works perfectly on WAMP. But not working on my web server.

Comment: Are you creating the directory dynamically using $ran variable

Comment: Have you actually checked that the file exists? Did you follow the exact url?

Comment: @zan no I am not creating directory dynamic.

Comment: @MikeSpy How I check that file is exists at "temp" folder.

Comment: Does the directory `/home/noyosdzy/public_html/jagdish/upload/users/jagdish/` already exist?

Comment: not sure but do you have permissions to create file where you are trying to upload it?

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue, but to be frank my issue was with a pipe character in the filename. please check whether your filename has any special characters.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507